# two way communication, each handling multiple connections, using raw sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am new to socket programming. I want to implement what's mentioned in the subject or you can call it a chatroom. My basic purpose is just to understand how it works. I have read many tutorials but could not find exactly what i was looking for.

I have following problems:

Q 1: I am having one computer. So I am using lo (local loop) as my interface. So whatever data I am sending,       I am receiving the same in the program in which I am first sending and then receiving. The vice versa is not a problem.

Q2.  I have not seen accept and connect calls in context of raw socket in any tutorial. Can I actually use these calls with raw sockets?

Comment: Well, if you are new to socket programming, you shall probably start with standard tcp/ip or udp/ip sockets. Raw ethernet packets are more difficult level.

Comment: Done that. I actually meant new to raw sockets and just completed normal sockets.

Comment: For Q2, no there is no connect or accept for raw sockets. Just like these are not used for UDP. You are bypassing the transport layer (TCP) which would use these.

Comment: What are you actually using this for? Be aware if you use raw sockets you will not be able to connect to 90% or more of normal consumers on cheap ISPs as non TCP or UDP or SCTP traffic cannot traverse NAT. Until I know what you actually are doing I cannot really offer useful advice.

Comment: @Vality I am just a student. Trying to learn. Got this assignment to do. That's why I am trying on my local host.

Comment: @DoxyLover , Thanks a lot. It developed my confidence. Now I can say this to my teacher quite confidently.. :)